# MySQL: parse and cast strings which contain numbers with units

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a column holding string values that are numbers and units. The values contain a numerical value in the prefix composed of integers and one decimal.

Some examples of these values would be following:

```
"16 GB", "8.5gb", "15.99345 GHz", "25L"
```

Is there a way I can use the cast function to first parse the string values that contain numbers and decimals and only do the cast on that portion of the values?

This is what I had in mind

```
select * from my_table
where cast( numparse( my_column ) as signed ) > 10
```

Thanks in advance, I'm fairly new to SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this one column in the first place? Why don't you store value and unit separated?

Comment: The `CAST()` function will do this all by itself.

Comment: If the numeric value is at the beginning of the string, `where my_column  > 10` should work just fine in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could write a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) that does some sort of string parsing, or [use a regex as in @ladd2025's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960378/14660)...

But then you'd be redoing this conversion on every query. There's the cost of the conversion, but it also means you cannot take advantage of indexing. A query like `where parse_the_thing( thing ) > 10` has to do a full table scan. Whereas if `thing` were an indexed number to begin with `where thing > 10` is a very fast indexed query. This a problem with storing "formatted" information, you have to strip the formatting every time you want to do something with it.

You'd be far better off normalizing your stored data to store the magnitude as a [numeric data type such as bigint, double, or numeric](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html), and the unit as an [enum column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html). Or consider if it makes sense to store all these different units in the same table; does it make sense to compare 8.5 gb with 15.99 Ghz?

`8.5gb` stored in bytes would become the `bigint` 8,500,000,000 (the exact value depends on whether it's 1000 bytes or 1024 bytes) with the unit `bytes`. `15.99345 GHz` might become the `bigint` 15,993,450,000 with the unit `Hz`. And so on.

You can accomplish this by adding the new columns to your table, and doing the update to convert from the strings to the units and quantity. And then change whatever is inputting the values to do the same. You can continue to store the original human formatted string if you like, but you might be better off not and applying the formatting as needed.

This makes your queries much simpler, less chance of bugs. And they can take advantage of indexing, so they'll be much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '[^0-9/.]', '') AS signed) > 10;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2c15e6c1e29eefbc7eb5009394951549)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `CAST()` function. If you're casting to a numeric type, it will just parse the prefix and ignore the rest.

```
mysql> select cast('12.45gb' as signed);
+---------------------------+
| cast('12.45gb' as signed) |
+---------------------------+
|                        12 |
+---------------------------+
```